# Visual Studio: How to push changes to a new Branch?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, git-branch

I have 100s of changes that I don't want to push to master.  Usually I start a new branch, and then merge later.

How can I create a new branch without losing my current changes?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/01UUu.jpg

Comment: commit your changes then create/checkout a new branch!

Comment: They are committed locally.  I just don't want to push them to master yet.

Answer (score 2):

To Save all changes in new branch without losing any data
First stash changes

> **`git stash -m "write_your_own_message"`**

Make your new branch

> `git checkout -b "new_branch"`

And get all changes in the current branch by this command

> `git stash apply`

If you have  more than one stash run this command to know stash number

> `git stash list`

And have a stash list like this

```
stash@{0}: On master: all chages in the files
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 44381e5 add files project
stash@{2}: On master: my changes
```

Apply stash by index number like this

> `git stash apply 0`

Answer (score 0):

Using visual studio

1. Commit your changes
2. Create new branch (as shown in your image, but **uncheck** checkout branch)
3. Right click the commit before -> reset -> hard reset -> ok (Now you are at the commit before, and your changes are in safe backup branch)
4. Checkout your new backup branch -> push (this will create a new branch at `origin` side).

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
git stash -m "my awesome changes"
```

After creating a new branch, just apply

```
git stash apply --index 0
```

If you have other stashes, then make sure you use the right index.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been making local changes, and you want to commit them to a new branch, just create the new branch and add them to it. It's ok to create a branch when there are uncommited changes present.

e.g.

On branch main:
Change 7 files. These changes are not committed.

git checkout -b my_new_branch

git add names-of-files-changed

OR

git add -u (means add any files which are in the git repo, but have changed. Does not add newly created files)

git commit -m"message describing changes"

main is where it was before your changes.
my_new_branch has your changes.